# children components are not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const rou = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <div>
        <Navbar
          title="TextUtils"
          mode={mode}
          toggleMode={toggleMode}
          btnText={btnText}
        />
        <Alert alert={alert} />
      </div>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: (
          <div className="container my-3">
            <Textform
              showAlert={showAlert}
              heading="Enter the text to analyze"
              mode={mode}
            /> 
          </div>
        ), 
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        element: (
          <div className="container my-3">
            <About />
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ]
  }
]);

return (
  <>  
    <RouterProvider router={rou} />
  </>
);
```

These are in my app but not rendering children component that is `Textform` and `About` instead only showing navbar and alert.

Answer (score 1):

Nested routes need their parent route to render an `Outlet` component to be able to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <div>
        <Navbar
          title="TextUtils"
          mode={mode}
          toggleMode={toggleMode}
          btnText={btnText}
        />
        <Alert alert={alert} />
        <Outlet /> // <-- render Outlet here for nested route content
      </div>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: (
          <div className="container my-3">
            <Textform
              showAlert={showAlert}
              heading="Enter the text to analyze"
              mode={mode}
            /> 
          </div>
        ), 
      },
      {
        path: '/about',
        element: (
          <div className="container my-3">
            <About />
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ]
  }
]);
```

```
<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

For more details/information see [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) and [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes).